# Use the Alt-Print key

Tags: 16.04, print-screen

I wanted to change the six `Print` bindings as I need a screenshot of a window much more often then a screenshot of the whole screen. I wanted to use the original key combinations, just permuted a bit.

This is the result:

[image: confused]

(Please ignore the `Ctrl-Insert`, this was my mistake made after a few trials).

You can see that I'm getting `Mod2` instead of `Print`!

What's worse: Pressing the left alt key alone seem blinks the scree (probably generating screenshots).

Comment: I have the same problem. I defined a custom shortcut and I want to use the Alt+Print binding, but when I add a "New accelerator" and press Alt+Print, the result is Mod2+Alt L. If you found a solution, please share!